# Joi validation when multiple conditions are met

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi, multiple-conditions

I need to validate one field of object when two fields of same object is true.
I have an object like

```
person={
 is_active: // either true or false
 is_valid: // either true or false
 username :'' // validation required field
}
```

so i have to do validation like

```
if (is_active==true && is_valid==true)
```

then only i have to validate username like

```
Joi.string().required()
```

I have tried the nested when condition but it throws Assertion Error

Answer (score 0):

use `is` clause as explained [here](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/622) for the username